# Problem with animating a character with no limbs

Tags: animation

I tried to make a player character akin to Rayman, and after trying to create an idle animation and exporting the file in .fbx the animation bugged out and animates only a part that is not even animated in the first place, and is in a spot that shouldn't even be.
However, I did try to animate without a skeleton, would that fix the problem?

I am new to blender and game developement, I basically picked it up 2-3 days ago and I've been grinding ever since, so if someone could also explain to me why this happened for the future I would be grateful.

[image: The Character]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you add more details on how you rigged the model, which game engine is used, does the animation work in Blender, is the model one object, etc? Reading your questions let me know: you made a nice Rayman-style character, the idle animation doesn't work when exported as FBX, and you're new to Blender. Not enough information to answer the question.

Comment: I didn't rig it at all, I use the unity game engine, but the picture is from the built in 3D model viewer for windows (looks the same in Unity too though), the animation works in Blender, the model is several objects, one for each body part, I don't really know what else I can add to this, like I said I'm new and learning as I go so I'm not yet familiar with all of the things of the program.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still not sure what you did. Have you created the model in Blender, exported it, and animated it in Unity? ... maybe checkout [Imphenzia's channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzfWju7SFoWLCyV_gDVCrGA). He has a lot of Blender and Unity videos like this one https://youtu.be/pwZpJzpE2lQ.

Comment: It appears to have fixed itself when I added a skeleton